# Checking whether function contains pass

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, python-3.5

I have one parent class `P` and several child classes. The parent class contains the method `doSomething(x)` defined only as:

```
def doSomething(self, x):
    pass
```

Now, some of `P`'s subclasses may have implemented this method, and some have not. Is there any way I can check if `doSomething(x)` is going to do nothing but `pass`, at runtime (e.g. if it is implemented, execute it, if not, skip it)?

Comment: Why skip it? It does nothing, so why bother?

Comment: And the ABC module would not help you detect no-op methods either.

Comment: You could return [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) instead, or raise a [`NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError).  The docs for `NotImplementedError` also mention setting the method to `None` if that class will never support that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do *anything* here other than just calling `doMethod()` on the instance. Calling a no-op method is not so costly that detecting when a child class has implemented an override is going to save you anything.

So your number 1 option is to *just call the method*, and don't worry about it being an empty method. That's what `pass` is *for*, to give you an easy parent class method that does nothing.

Next, you state

> Parent class contains method `doSomething(x)`

You can use this to detect if you have that method still; the underlying function for the bound method is going to be the same object:

```
hook = instance.doSomething
if hook.__func__ is ParentClass.doSomething:
    # they didn't override the method, so nothing needs to be done.
```

Again, I'm not sure why anyone would want to do that, because that test is not going to save you anything over just using `instance.doSomething()`.

Next, a function that consists solely of the statement `pass` will be compiled to the same bytecode, always; it's the same bytecode as `return None`. Compare the bytecode if you must know if a function is empty:

```
_RETURN_NONE = (lambda: None).__code__.co_code

def is_pass(f):
    return f.__code__.co_code == _RETURN_NONE
```

This can be applied to any function or method that, in essence, only ever returns `None` and does nothing else.

Demo:

```
>>> class P:
...     def doSomething(self, x):
...         pass
...
>>> class Child1(P):
...     def doSomething(self, x):
...         print("We are doing something with {!r}!".format(x))
...
>>> class Child2(P):
...     pass
...
>>> instance1 = Child1()
>>> instance2 = Child2()
>>> instance1.doSomething(42)
We are doing something with 42!
>>> instance2.doSomething(42)
>>> instance1.doSomething.__func__ is P.doSomething
False
>>> instance2.doSomething.__func__ is P.doSomething
True
>>> is_pass(instance1.doSomething)
False
>>> is_pass(instance2.doSomething)
True
>>> def unrelated_function():
...     return 42
...
>>> def another_unrelated_function():
...     pass
...
>>> is_pass(unrelated_function)
False
>>> is_pass(another_unrelated_function)
True
```

Note how `is_pass()` works on any function that uses `pass`.

Answer (score 2):

Since your parent method is defined as

```
def doSomething(x):
    pass
```

It does nothing - it is cheaper to just call it instead of verifying if it has been overriden or not. It will be automatically "skipped" because it does nothing in first place.

That said, if you really want to test for it, you can do something like this

```
if type(some_instance).doSomething is ParentClass.doSomething:
     print('Not overriden')
else:
     print('Function has been overriden, call it'):
     some_instance.doSomething()
```